# make4ht fails in TeXLive2023 but works in TexLive2022; pdflatex works in both (\pdfstringdef)

Tags: texlive, make4ht

This is question is different than the Tikz package, etc.

I am compiling this document:

- https://github.com/NAG-DevOps/speed-hpc/tree/master/doc

like so in the corresponding [`Makefile`](https://github.com/NAG-DevOps/speed-hpc/blob/master/doc/Makefile)

```
# Building static HTML requires `make4ht`
# Works with existing environment
html:
        make4ht $(DELIVERABLE) -a debug mathjax -c speed-manual.cfg -d web && \
        mv ./web/$(DELIVERABLE).html ./web/index.html && \
        rm $(DELIVERABLE).html $(DELIVERABLE).css
```

After upgrading our systems to TeXLive 2023 the following error started popping up. It only happens with `make4ht` and not `pdflatex`. If I let it run, it appears to produce coherent output, but blocks automation. I had to revert to TeXLive 2022 where the error goes away.

```
(/encs/pkg/texlive-20230324/root/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)
(../src/tcsh.sh) [30] [31] [32] [33] [34] [35] [36] [37] [38] [39]
(../src/tmpdir.sh) [40]) [41] [42] [43] [44] (./scheduler-job-examples.tex
[45] [46] (../src/fluent.sh) [47] [48] [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55]
[56] [57]) [58] (./scheduler-tips.tex [59]) [60] [61] (./scheduler-faq.tex
[62] [63] [64] [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71]) [72] [73]
(./speed-manual.bbl [74]) [75] [76]

enddocument/afterlastpage: lastpage setting LastPage.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...Hy@unicodefalse \Hy@PageAnchorSlide 
                                                  \pdfstringdef \@the@H@page...
l.659 \end{document}
                    
? 
(./speed-manual.aux) )
Output written on speed-manual.dvi (76 pages, 207752 bytes).
Transcript written on speed-manual.log.
```

How can I fix this and move to TeXLive 2023?

Comment: I will not download an external document to debug it and certainly not one which has lots of inputs and creates 76 pages. It is your job to reduce that to a manageable size and to show a small but complete example here.

Comment: I really don't know why it says 76 pages... The actual document is 29, but I get your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incidentally, I got the exact same bug reported a few days ago and literally posted the fix to TeX4ht sources an hour ago.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

It seems that the Lastpage package uses the internal Hyperref command `\Hy@PageAnchorSlide`, but Hyperref doesn't define it in TeX4ht mode.

As a fix, use the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
  \def\Hy@PageAnchorSlidesPlain{}%
  \def\Hy@PageAnchorSlide{}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: actually I just discuss with the lastpage maintainer that this code should be removed again.

Comment: So who's "fault" is this, LastPage's or make4ht's? I'll test out the config proposed above, but it's not a long-term fix I suppose? Seems like good timing on these fixes... Thank you both/

Comment: Confirm it works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it seems that this command does something useful only with the Slide class? I've added the dummy definition to `hyperref.4ht` to prevent other issues in the future. Maybe they use that command in Lastpage because it can provide something useful with the Slide class? BTW, I don't recall that I ever heard about this class before.

Comment: @Serguei It should work after next TeX Live update, probably in next few days.

Comment: @michal.h21 lastpage tries to find out the name of the pageanchor and copied for this the internal hyperref code without thinking about tex4ht. But it will revert this as I will provide a real interface in the next hyperref version.